# MYSQL Query search in relationship

Tags: mysql

For the sake of clarity and this question i will rename the tables so it is a bit clearer for everybody and explain what i want to achieve:

There is an input form with options that return categories ID's. If a 'Product' has 'Category', i want to return/find the 'Product' which lets say has multiple categories(or just 1) and all of its categories are inside the array that is passed from the form.

Products table

```
ID     Title
1      Pizza
2      Ice Cream
```

Categories table

```
ID     Title
1      Baked food
2      Hot food
```

ProductsCategories table

```
ID     ProductId     CategoryId
1      1             1  
2      1             2
```

So if i pass [1,2] the query should return Product with id 1 since all ProductsCategories are inside the requested array, but if i pass only 1 or 2, the query should return no results.

Currently i have the following query which works, but for some reason if i create a second Product and create a ProductCategory that has a CategoryId same as the first product, the query returns nulll...

```
 SELECT products.*
 FROM products
 JOIN products_categories
 ON products_categories.product_id= products.id
 WHERE products_categories.category_id IN (1, 2)
 HAVING COUNT(*) = (select count(*) from products_categories pc 
     WHERE pc  .product_id = products.id)
```

All help is deeply appretiated! Cheers!

Comment: so to clear your question, you want only products that are in multiple categories only, not in single one?

Comment: @mitkosoft, if i search for Categories with id's [1,2,5,10] i want to get all the products that all of their categories are inside that array. In other words :
Product with id 1 has records in ProductsCategories with category_id's 1 and 2. If the search array is [1,2,5,10] the product should be returned, but if the product ProducsCategories with category_id's 1,2 and 8 (which is not in the search array), then the product should not be returned.
I know the case seems a bit messed up, but there is not other way to accomplish the task if the query is not that strict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mitkosoft, thanks for your answer, but sadly the query is not producing the needed results. If the product's categories are partially in the passed categories the product is still returned. Additionally i might not know how many parameters are sent by the form.

Luckily I managed to create the query that does the trick and works perfectly fine (at least so far)

```
SELECT products.*,    
COUNT(*) as resultsCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products_categories pc WHERE pc.product_id = products.id) as categoriesCount

FROM products
JOIN products_categories AS productsCategories
ON productsCategories.product_id= products.id
WHERE productsCategories.category_id IN (7, 15, 8, 1, 50)

GROUP BY products.id
HAVING resultsCount = categoriesCount
ORDER BY amount DESC #optional
```

That way the query is flexible and gives me exactly what I needed! - Only those products that have all their categories inside the search parameters(not partially).

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to match all values in `IN` clause, you just need to know in addition the number of passed categories which you must use it in `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    p.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.title) AS categories
FROM
    Products p
    INNER JOIN ProductsCategories pc ON pc.productId = p.ID
    INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.ID = pc.categoryId
WHERE
    pc.categoryId IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
    p.id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT pc.categoryId) = 2 -- this is # of unique categories in IN clause
```

So in case `IN (1,2)` result is:

```
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | title | categories          |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Pizza | Baked Food,Hot Food |
+----+-------+---------------------+
1 row in set
```

In case `IN (1,3)` result is `Empty set` (no results).